# Visual Studio Python: add internal folder as module

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015

I try to run my python project in visual studio 2015.
(Simple single tests are already working.)

When I run my project I got this error:
**ImportError: No module named one_of_my_subfolder.helloworld**

```
from one_of_my_subfolder.helloworld import TestClassXY
```

In my structure, this is a folder and a python file:

```
/one_of_my_subfolder
     helloworld.py
```

I already added this and the parent folder to "Add Folder to Search Path" but it does not work. It almost seems as if he ignores the given paths.
By the way: The same code works with Eclipse. There you have the possibility to add src folders to the python path.

Comment: Is there an `__init__.py` file in the subfolder?

Comment: Yes it is.  The same code/structure still works with Eclipse.